# Word for paying for a group purchase (eg. dinner) on a credit card and collecting cash from the other members of the group

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for paying for a group purchase, like dinner, on a credit card and collecting cash from the other members of the group?

I had a friend who used to call this “snorgling”, but he made up that term himself. I’m not sure if snorgling was specifically used to describe when the person paying on the credit card was receiving some sort of credit card rewards.

Comment: In what circumstances would you use such a word?

Comment: When you decide to use that method, presumably! (and, no, I don't know of a word for it.)

Comment: Oo! Look! In 2006, someone else made it up too: "**snorgle**: *To snorgle is to to snuggle a cute item in an manner meant to drink in or experience its overwhelming cuteness. Imagine picking up a cute puppy and sticking your face down into its furriness and snorgling it up.* See cuteoverload dot com. -- *"She scooped up the shar pei puppy and snorgled its rolls of puppy fat."* https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=snorgle

Comment: There's no regular term, I guess you'd say something like *I'll handle the payment/money* or *I'll pay and you can give me the money/settle with me/pay me back later*. Maybe some people have personal/local/group slang.

Comment: Greybeard's answer that there is no such word is probably the true one, but if the word exists, it is possible that the contributors to [Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com/) know it, even if nobody on this site does.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few people, native-speakers and others alike, who think that English has a word for everything: it doesn't.

The answer is "There is no accepted word for this."

Comment: Probably true, but quite a claim when even OED insists that (to paraphrase) 'non-inclusion does not mandate that a candidate word isn't a valid word'.

Comment: It is a valid use of language to kill all hope in the mind of a questioner. 40 views by some of the finest minds available and in 8 hours. I'm putting a fiver on "no word being discovered within the next year."

Comment: Related: [Is "There is no answer" an acceptable answer?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15396).